# setting up databases for associations on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, seeding

First time working on ruby on rails and I have an app with the following 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :name, :email, :password
  has_many :comments
  has_many :ideas, :inverse_of => :user
end

class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :rank, :user_id, :status, :privacy, :created_on, :updated_on
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :ideas
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :rank, :user_id, :idea_id, :created_on
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :idea
end
```

I have a table for Comments created like:

```
create_table :comments do |t|
    t.string :comment_id
    t.string :text
    t.string :rank
    t.timestamps
end
```

I am trying to seed for these.  What I'm trying to understand is how a single comment with a parent idea and a parent user is stored in the database, since the columns can only hold one parent at a time.  Should I create a separate table that holds comment_id, user_id and idea_type, where a single comment gets entered in twice for each parent?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe which relationship you are wanting to be polymorphic? Are you trying to support comments on both Ideas and Users, or just on Users? And are there potentially subclasses of User?

Comment: I want support comments on both Users and Ideas.  I want Comments to be polymorphic.  I don't think there is subclasses

Comment: Are you sure that polymorphism is actually what you're looking for? You would use polymorphism if you wanted comments to be left on either ideas or users, that is it would have either a parent user or idea, but only one of the two. Is that what you want, or do you actually want a comment to belong to a user (who left it), and an idea (the idea being commented on). If that is the case, then you don't need a polymorphic relationship, just two `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationships.

Comment: Yeah, are you trying to track that a particular User has commented on an Idea? That would be more like a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) relationship. I think we first need to be sure our relationship structure is correct before offering a solution.

Comment: Thanks Zaid!  Completely on the nose with the later.  So given that, would I just create a join table that has both user and idea ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to implement Comment as a join model which indicates that a particular User's comment on an Idea. If so, you should be able to accomplish that as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :name, :email, :password
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_ideas, :class_name => 'Idea', :through => :comments, :source => :comment
end

class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :rank, :user_id, :status, :privacy, :created_on, :updated_on
  belongs_to :user  # the user who created the Idea
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_users, :class_name => 'User', :through => :comments, :source => :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :rank, :user_id, :idea_id, :created_on
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :idea
end

create_table :comments do |t|
  t.string :text
  t.string :rank
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :idea_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Thanks stuart.  I have a question about extending this.  Would it be possible to add belongs_to :user to Idea model as the user who created the idea on top of commented users?

Comment: thanks!  So, theoretically, I could keep extending the associations like so to describe any situation?

Comment: Yeah well what you basically have here is a **Join model**, where you are describing a relationship between two other models (User and Idea) but also storing attributes about that relationship itself (such as the text of the comment, timestamp when it was made, etc). You can reuse this pattern whenever you have a many-to-many relationship but also want to have properties _about_ each connection. See the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I've looked the Rails guide up and down, but still didn't really understand well enough to implement my model